# I am unable to make my timed, random color generator work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create some JavaScript code that will change the background color of an element, in this case a jumbotron, every 8 seconds. I have done lots of research online and used some of the tips I found but I still cannot make it work. All code is below including the HTML, CSS and JavaScript I am using. Any suggestions would be great, but please remember I am just learning JavaScript. This is my first stackoverflow question.

```html
<html>

<style>
  .jumbocolors {
    position: absolute;
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
</style>

<body onload="color_timer()">
  <div>
    <jumbotron id="jumbo1" class="jumbocolors">Sample Text</jumbotron>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  function color_timer() {
    var timer;
    var finished = false;
    while (!finished) {
      timer = setTimeout(random_color(), 8000);
      finished = random_color();
    }
  }

  function random_color() {
    var R_random = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    var G_random = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    var B_random = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    var elem = document.getElementById("jumbo1");
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(R_random, G_random, B_random)';
    return false;
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: It's `Math.random()` not `math.random()`!!!

Comment: [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: Check your browser console, you have a bunch of errors.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the Math.random().

Comment: and `getElementById`, not `getelementbyID`

Comment: Thanks guys, guess I need to start using the browser console more. I saw all those in there when I did. I kind of expect Brackets to show me those errors but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few errors throughout this code.

1. You need to capitalize various characters correctly in `document.getElementById()` as well as capitalize the `Math` function.
2. This string `'rgb(R_random, G_random, B_random)'` is not actually pulling the javascript variables into the string. It should be rewritten as: `'rgb(' + R_random + ', ' + G_random + ', ' + B_random +')'`
3. There is a much simpler way to set a timer using `setInterval` to change the color every 8 seconds. Check out the updated code below:

```html
<html>

<style>
  .jumbocolors {
    position: absolute;
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
</style>

<body onload="color_timer()">
  <div>
    <jumbotron id="jumbo1" class="jumbocolors">Sample Text</jumbotron>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  function color_timer() {
    setInterval(function(){
      random_color();
    },8000);
  }

  function random_color() {
    var R_random = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    var G_random = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    var B_random = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    var elem = document.getElementById("jumbo1");
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + R_random + ', ' + G_random + ', ' + B_random +')';
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: IT WORKS! You rock, thank you so much. Now I am gonna add a transition-duration to that and I'll have exactly what I want. Thanks again.

Comment: @Timothy you are very welcome! If this answer solved your problem you can use the checkmark underneath the voting arrows to mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in this code - using the browser console will be crucial to debugging as you write JavaScript.

The first error is that `Math` must be capitalized.

The second error is that the function to select by Id is not properly cased, it must be `document.getElementById`.

The third error is that there is no need for a loop - you can just use `setInterval` to run a function every `n` milliseconds.

The fourth error is that in your `setTimeout` you are invoking your function rather than passing in the function definition.

The fifth error is that you need to properly concatenate the string to build the new backgroundColor. Not an error, but you also don't need to `parseInt()` the result of the random color numbers.

Please see the following revised working code:

```
<html>
  <style>
    .jumbocolors {
      position: absolute;
      height: 250px;
      width: 500px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 60px;
    }
  </style>

  <body onload="color_timer()">
    <div>
      <jumbotron id="jumbo1" class="jumbocolors">Sample Text</jumbotron>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    function color_timer() {
      setInterval(random_color, 8000);
    }

    function random_color() {
      var R_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var G_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var B_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      var elem = document.getElementById("jumbo1");
      elem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + R_random + ',' + G_random + ',' + B_random + ')';
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you hackerrdave, I appreciate it.